# Opening an Android App Link will cause Android System to Crash

Tags: android

I wanted to see if anyone else is running into this issue. I have Android App Links setup for my app and site. Things were working fine, but after I've updated the gradle wrapper and other libraries every time my I try my Android App Link it will cause Android to throw the modal that says...

"Unfortunately, Android System has stopped"

And it will not open my application. However it works when i try to open using the traditional URI scheme deeplink.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the error log, that helps with determining what is the cause of the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The issue was that my icon was too big for the device to render on the modal that pops up. Changing that to an appropriate size fixed it.

Comment: Congratulations. Please share your icon size, and precise description about solution for community. Then I will upvote you.